# printing in python a twitter response

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I am making a request to a twitter URL

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_obj)
```

If I do this:

```
for data in response:
        print(data)
```

I get a response from it that contains all the data, username, location etc.

```
{"users":[{"id":2190618097,"id_str":"2190618097","name":"huramachi","screen_name":"huramachi73","location":"entre Vincennes et R
    \u00e9publique ","description":"Nuclear winter is coming!!!","
```

So, that is json.

And if I do this:

```
json.dumps(parsed, indent= 4, sort_keys=True)
```

it looks like this:

```
 {
    "next_cursor": 1591504703761404265, 
    "next_cursor_str": "1591504703761404265", 
    "previous_cursor": 0, 
    "previous_cursor_str": "0", 
    "users": [
        {
            "blocked_by": false, 
            "blocking": false, 
            "contributors_enabled": false, 
            "created_at": "Tue Nov 12 16:07:59 +0000 2013", 
            "default_profile": true, 
            "default_profile_image": false, 
            "description": "Nuclear winter is coming!!!", 
            "entities": {
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            }, 
            "favourites_count": 781, 
            "follow_request_sent": false, 
            "followers_count": 188, 
            "following": false, 
            "friends_count": 2054,
```

If I do this, I get the info that parsed is a dictionary.

```
parsed = json.loads(response.text)
    print (type(parsed))
```

but how do I print this dictionary, or organize it so that I can save entities in lists?

Comment: Can you print `eachloop` without fetch by `name`? I want to know what `eachloop` is container.

Comment: what you ask is already done right above, it is the first thing I tried.

Comment: Can you put `print eachloop` instead of `print eachloop['name']` and then run your code, want to see the output ...and then we can find the reason ..BTW, you can add `print eachloop, type(eachloop)`

Comment: again, what you are saying is the same thing that is written above with keys, It brings the whole text, everything without spaces. You can see the output.

Comment: but no complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, thanks to all those who tried to help.

Here is what worked for me and why.

Why:
Twitter returns a json response but this object has parents and childrens, so the printing can only be complete if you nest your loops and you know who the parent and the children are according to twitter dev docs:

Tweets are the basic atomic building block of all things Twitter. Tweets are also known as “status updates.” The Tweet object has a long list of ‘root-level’ attributes, including fundamental attributes such as id, created_at, and text. Tweet objects are also the ‘parent’ object to several child objects. Tweet child objects include user, entities, and extended_entities. Tweets that are geo-tagged will have a place child object.

You can see in there several print outs of how their json looks like and also in mine own print out above.

So, if I want to print out one of the children, for example, location, this is what worked for me:

```
objeto = json.loads(response.text)
    for element in objeto['users']:
        print (element['location'])
```